# Check if a directory exists recursively reversing the path

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I am kind of confused here ! I am not sure how to put forth the question .

May be with an example .

I am in the process of writing a bash script which checks if a specific folder named "FNS" is in the current directory . To check if the file exists ,I do this.

```
        FOLDER=FNS
        if [ -f $FOLDER ];
        then
        echo "File $FOLDER exists"
        else
        # do the thing
        fi
```

The problem arises If  the file doesnt exists ! I want the script to take a note of the current path and move back a directory [ I meant cd .. in the command line ,I am not sure if I am using the correct vocabulary here] and check if the file exists and if not, again move back one step, until the directory in which it exist shows up [ it is sure to exist ] .When found store the path in a variable .
The present directory of execution should not change.I tried passing the `pwd` to a variable and cutting till the last slash and  some other stuffs without success !

Hope I can do something in this regard .
Like always suggestions,algorithms and work arounds are welcome :)

Comment: Do you need to build your own script? Using `find` command wouldn't be useful to you?

Comment: @Ander2: `find -maxdepth 1` would be the same and without `-maxdepth` it could be too slow if you want to look only along one chain of directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, with parentheses starts a subshell so the cd command does not change current directory of current shell

```
(while [ ! -d "$FOLDER" ];do cd ..;done;pwd)
```

Comment: +1: note that `pwd` should be replaced with whatever actions must be performed in the directory containing FNS, since the location (and value of any assigned variable) will be lost when the subshell exits.  Just replace `pwd` with a call to the function that does the work.

Answer (score 1):

The bash *pushd* and *popd* built-in commands could help you.
In pseudocode:

```
function FolderExists() { ... }

cds = 0
while (NOT FolderExists) {
    pushd ..
    cds=cds+1;
}

store actual dir using pwd command

for(i=0;i<cds;i++) {
    popd
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl`.

Content of `script.pl` (the directory is hard-coded but it's easy to modify the program to read it as an argument):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Spec;
use List::Util qw|first|;

## This variable sets to 1 after searching in the root directory.
my $try;

## Original dir to begin searching.
my $dir = File::Spec->rel2abs( shift ) or die;

do {
    ## Check if dir 'FNS' exists in current directory. Print
    ## absolute dir and finish in that case.
    my $d = first { -d && m|/FNS$| } <$dir/*>;
    if ( $d ) { 
        printf qq|%s\n|, File::Spec->rel2abs( $d );    
        exit 0;
    }   

    ## Otherwise, goto up directory and carry on the search until
    ## we reach to root directory.
    my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir( $dir );
    $dir = File::Spec->catdir( @dirs[0 .. ( $#dirs - 1 || 0 )] )
} while ( $dir ne File::Spec->rootdir || $try++ == 0);
```

Run it with a directory where the search will begin. It can be relative or absolute path. Like this:

```
perl script.pl /home/birei/temp/dev/everychat/
```

or

```
perl script.pl .
```

It will print the absolute path if found the directory. An example of my test:

```
/home/birei/temp/FNS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=/path/to/starting/dir    # or $PWD perhaps
seekdir=FNS

while [[ ! -d $dir/$seekdir ]]
do
    if [[ -z $dir ]]    # at /
    then
        if [[ -d $dir/$seekdir ]]
        then
            break    # found in /
        else
            echo "Directory $seekdir not found"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
    dir=${dir%/*}
done

echo "Directory $seekdir exists in $dir"
```

Note that the `-f` test is for regular files. If you want to test for directories, use `-d` as I have.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/bin/bash

FOLDER="FNS"
FPATH="${PWD}"
P="../"

if [ -d ${FOLDER} ];

then 

    FPATH="$(readlink -f ${FOLDER})"
    FOLDER="${FPATH}"
    echo "FNS: " $FPATH

else

    while [ "${FOLDER}" != "${FPATH}" ] ; do
    NEXT="${P}${FOLDER}"    

    if [ -d "${NEXT}" ];
    then
        FPATH=$(readlink -f ${NEXT})
        FOLDER="${FPATH}"
        echo "FNS: " $FPATH
    else
        P="../${P}"
    fi

    done

fi
```